# Get count of consecutive days meeting a given criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following structure in my Oracle database:

```
Date          Allocation  id
2015-01-01    Same        200
2015-01-02    Good        200
2015-01-03    Same        200
2015-01-04    Same        200
2015-01-05    Same        200
2015-01-06    Good        200
```

I would like to have a query that has to check for only the previous consecutive days and get the count where Allocation is `"Same"`.

I want to select by a date, for example `2015-01-05`.
Example output: for the date `2015-01-05` the count is `3`.

New problem. With the query from Lukas Eder the count is always `1` or `2`. but the expected is `3`. Why?!

```
Date          Allocation  id
2015-01-01    Same        400
2015-01-02    Good        400
2015-01-03    Same        400
2015-01-04    Same        400
2015-01-05    Same        400
2015-01-06    Good        400
```

Code from Lukas Eder

```
 SELECT c
    FROM (
      SELECT allocation, d, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY allocation, part ORDER BY d) AS c
      FROM (
        SELECT allocation, d,
               d - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY allocation ORDER BY d) AS part
        FROM t
      )
    )
    WHERE d = DATE '2015-01-05';
```

The expected output is something like this, First_day end Last day not necessary:

```
id   count    first_day   Last_Day
200  3        2015-01-03  2015-01-05
400  3        2015-01-03  2015-01-05
```

Comment: Can you show us what query you have tried?

Comment: look at lag and lead functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will yield the counts for each row:

```
SELECT allocation, d, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY allocation, part ORDER BY d) AS c
FROM (
  SELECT allocation, d,
         d - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY allocation ORDER BY d) AS part
  FROM t
)
ORDER BY d;
```

You can then filter on it to find the counts for a given row:

```
SELECT c
FROM (
  SELECT allocation, d, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY allocation, part ORDER BY d) AS c
  FROM (
    SELECT allocation, d,
           d - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY allocation ORDER BY d) AS part
    FROM t
  )
)
WHERE d = DATE '2015-01-05';
```

#### Explanation:

The derived table is used to calculate different "partitions" `part` for each date and allocation:

```
  SELECT allocation, d,
         d - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY allocation ORDER BY d) AS part
  FROM t
```

The result is:

```
allocation  d           part
--------------------------------
Same        01.01.15    31.12.14
Good        02.01.15    01.01.15
Same        03.01.15    01.01.15
Same        04.01.15    01.01.15
Same        05.01.15    01.01.15
Good        06.01.15    04.01.15
```

The concrete date produced by `part` is irrelevant. It's just some date that will be the same for each "group" of dates within an allocation. You can then count the number of identical values of `(allocation, part)` using the `count(*) over(...)` window function:

```
SELECT allocation, d, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY allocation, part ORDER BY d) AS c
FROM (...)
ORDER BY d;
```

to produce your wanted result.

#### Data

I've used the following table for the example:

```
CREATE TABLE t AS (
  SELECT DATE '2015-01-01' AS d, 'Same' AS allocation FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2015-01-02' AS d, 'Good' AS allocation FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2015-01-03' AS d, 'Same' AS allocation FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2015-01-04' AS d, 'Same' AS allocation FROM dual UNION ALL  
  SELECT DATE '2015-01-05' AS d, 'Same' AS allocation FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2015-01-06' AS d, 'Good' AS allocation FROM dual
);
```

Comment: @MeesvanZ: Oh, I had overlooked the "previous" bit. I've adapted the query by adding `ORDER BY d` to the `COUNT(*) OVER (...)` window function. Is that more like it? Otherwise, it's usually a good idea to display the expected output in the question, to avoid any doubt.

Comment: pls see my post again, really want your help

Comment: @MeesvanZ: What is the expected output? Please, can you add the expected output in your question?

Comment: @MeesvanZ: Man, you totally changed that question! That's confusing. At some point, my answer was correct (twice, I would believe). Please, can you make that question consistent? Please, try asking a more consistent question from the beginning, in the future. Another option is not to edit the question inconsistently but accept the correct answer (correct with respect to the question) and ask a new, separate question.

Comment: I agree with @LukasEder

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following query to solve your problem:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count` FROM test t
WHERE `date` < '2015-01-05' AND allocation = 'Same';
```

Let's assume that the given date is '2015-01-05'. The idea here is to select all dates that are less than '2015-01-05' which means its previous days. Since allocation must be 'Same' so it's also included in condition section of statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT  count(Allocation) as total_allocation FROM table_name 
WHERE (Date BETWEEN CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE()) 
AND (Allocation='Same');
```

This will fetch all the records from date before today's date and whose Allocation='Same'

Answer (score 0):

It's easier:

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/98a9d/6)

```
SELECT count(*) AS c
FROM t
WHERE d <
TO_DATE (
       '2015-01-05'
        ,'yyyy-mm-dd'
)
AND allocation = 'Same';
```

Comment: This query will return the overall count of 'Same' records, not the consecutive days count. The result is 3 and not 4 in your example only because the date filter is "less than" and does not count 2015-01-05