# Oracle - Count consecutive days meeting the same given criteria

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following structure in my Oracle database:

```
Date          Allocation  id
2015-01-01    Same        200
2015-01-02    Good        200
2015-01-03    Same        200
2015-01-04    Same        200
2015-01-05    Same        200
2015-01-06    Good        200
```

I would like to have a query that has to check for only the previous consecutive days and get the count where Allocation is `"Same"`.

I want to select by a date, for example `2015-01-05`.
Example output: for the date `2015-01-05` the count is `3`.

New problem. With the query from Lukas Eder the count is always `1` or `2`. but the expected is `3`. from 2015-01-03 to 2015-01-05.

```
Date          Allocation  id
2015-01-01    Same        400
2015-01-02    Good        400
2015-01-03    Same        400
2015-01-04    Same        400
2015-01-05    Same        400
2015-01-06    Good        400
```

Code from Lukas Eder

```
 SELECT c
    FROM (
      SELECT allocation, d, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY allocation, part ORDER BY d) AS c
      FROM (
        SELECT allocation, d,
               d - row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY allocation ORDER BY d) AS part
        FROM t
      )
    )
    WHERE d = DATE '2015-01-05';
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get count of consecutive days meeting a given criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30725730/get-count-of-consecutive-days-meeting-a-given-criteria)

Comment: I realize this post contains a new problem, but it's really the same question. The "new problem" is that the old answer was insufficient; the core problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the groups by using a different of rows.  That is what your query is doing. If you then want the value on a particular date, use:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (order by date) -
              row_number() over (partition by allocation order by date)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
where d = date '2015-01-05';
```

My best guess as to why the version in your question doesn't work is because your `date` might have a time component.  I'm assuming that `d` is the `date` column.

EDIT:

To get the count, use a subquery and `count(*)` as an analytic function:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by grp, allocation) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by date) -
                    row_number() over (partition by allocation order by date)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
      ) t
where d = date '2015-01-05';
```

Or, you can use aggregation if you just want the count:

```
      select date, count(*) as cnt
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by date) -
                    row_number() over (partition by allocation order by date)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
      group by date, allocation
      having date = date '2015-01-05';
```

Comment: Thx. This doesn't give me the count of "same" used in consecutive days.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a whirl:

```
    create table mbtmp(d_date date, alloc varchar2(20), id number);

insert into mbtmp values (to_date('2015-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd'),'SAME',200);
insert into mbtmp values (to_date('2015-01-02','yyyy-mm-dd'),'GOOD',200);
insert into mbtmp values (to_date('2015-01-03','yyyy-mm-dd'),'SAME',200);
insert into mbtmp values (to_date('2015-01-04','yyyy-mm-dd'),'SAME',200);
insert into mbtmp values (to_date('2015-01-05','yyyy-mm-dd'),'SAME',200);
insert into mbtmp values (to_date('2015-01-06','yyyy-mm-dd'),'GOOD',200);
COMMIT;

SELECT max(length(sames) - length(replace(sames,'|',null)) - 1) from ( 
select regexp_substr( pth,'[|SAME]+') sames 
FROM(
   SELECT sys_connect_by_path(alloc,'|') pth  
    from mbtmp m
    WHERE d_Date > ( select max(d_date) from mbtmp 
                     where d_Date < to_date('2015-01-05','yyyy-mm-dd')
                      And alloc != 'SAME' )
    START WITH d_Date = to_date('2015-01-05','yyyy-mm-dd')
    CONNECT BY Prior d_date = d_date + 1));
```

Now, if not for the consecutive day rule, i.e. - if you still count even if there is a gap in the list of days, then you can use a much simpler query:

```
select count(d_Date)
    FROM mbtmp
    WHERE d_Date > ( select max(d_date) from mbtmp 
                      where d_Date < to_date('2015-01-05','yyyy-mm-dd')
                      And alloc != 'SAME' )
    and   d_date <= to_date('2015-01-05','yyyy-mm-dd')
```